# How can we handle dynamic values generated in Pop Ups in loadrunner?

Tags: dynamic, popup, correlation, loadrunner

I have generated a Web HTTP/HTML script using Load Runner 11 which eventually generates a ID at the end of the flow which i want to capture and store for future use.

The issue here is that the ID which i want to capture gets generted in a pop up. I am able to find the same ID in the generation logs but it fails when i reply the script. I searched it in the tree view but couldnt find the ID or its boundary anywhere.

In the generation logs its gets generated in a try block as below:

`doAfterLoading = function() {
            try {

                View.message('KYC NA Result: KYC IS COMPLETE<br/>ECI ID - 0222537179<br/>Cash Equity Indicator: N<br/>STP to CASS NA.<br/>STP Result/s:<br/>Message ID: 030102103<br/>Call To STP is Successful.<br>CASS ID: 36035151<br><br/> Account has been Approved.<br/>866131670', 400, function() {
                                        window.location.href = 'account?action=cleanup&NextAction=ViewSubmission'
                                    })
                    }`

I want to capture **CASS ID: 36035151** above. I need this info to be used for another script which uses the captured ID.

Can anybody help me deal with the dynamic values in pop up?

Comment: Could you elaborate on the nature of the pop-up? Is it an iFrame in the same window? A new window? Did you try to record using TruClient?

Answer (score 0):

What your GUI looks like does not matter with an HTTP virtual user.  You are recording at the transport level and not at the GUI level, so your comment regarding "in a popup" lacks an architectural basis for your virtual user type (different level of the OSI model).

A standard web_reg_save_param will work in this case.  You simply need to understand precisely which request generates the return data stream you need to interrogate.   Comment heavily as you record, including the values that you will need to collect off of the screen.   Then search for your comment and transaction names which bracket the area of interest.   It is entirely possible that you may need to turn to URL mode of you have a complex set of information being returned and you need to interrogate a specific item.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually i have already tried URL mode and also the commenting part which you suggested. The URL mode gives the same request above which i should be placing my web_reg_save_param function. As per the generation logs i should be placing my correlation function like: